# Gradle add dependency throw the method dependencies.add

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

My plan is to write less boilerplate code, and i have planned to do a method that will add dependency throw it, here is my method

```
project.ext{
    forEachWithKNp1 = { String[] items, Closure op ->
        final int length = items.length / 2;
        for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
            op(items[index], items[index + 1]);
        }
    }

    addSquareUpArtifacts = { String... names ->
        forEachWithKNp1(names, { name, version ->
            project.dependencies {
                getDependencies().add("compile", "com.squareup.$name:$name:$version")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When i try to sync a project, the error is occuring
`Error:(32, 0) A problem occurred evaluating project ':my-project'.`

What am i doing wrong? (i'm noobie in groovy and gradle, i tried to find out in the gradle documentation, and searched throw the Github, nothing useful was found)

Answer (score -1):

I made some researches, so i understood whats wrong, in `addSquareUpArtifacts` method i'm using variable `project` that is root project, instead i should used specify project to add dependency

here is final solution

```
project.ext{
    forEachWithKNp1 = { String[] items, Closure op ->
        final int length = items.length / 2;
        for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
            op(items[index], items[index + 1]);
        }
    }

    addSquareUpArtifact = {String projectPath, String... names ->
        final Project target = project.project(projectPath)

        forEachWithKNp1(names, { name, version ->
            target.getDependencies().add('compile', "com.squareup.$name:$name:$version")
        })
    }
}
```